# Hide a row with a checkbox in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide a row in jQuery when a checkbox is checked. It works but only for the first row with the ID, not others. Do you know why ?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#XL_TCG').change(function () {
        if (!this.checked) 
            $('#TCG').fadeIn('slow');
        else 
            $('#TCG').fadeOut('slow');
    });
    $('#XL_TCG').change();
});
```

My HTML:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr id="TCG">
         <td>Data 1</td>
         <td>Data 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Data 3</td>
         <td>Data 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="TCG">
         <td>Data 5</td>
         <td>Data 6</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Change `id´s` to `class` and use `this`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have multiple elements with the same id. IDs must be unique otherwise your page will not work properly. For multiple items, use classes instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#XL_TCG').change(function () {
        if (!this.checked) 
            $('.TCG').fadeIn('slow');
        else 
            $('.TCG').fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='checkbox' id='XL_TCG'>

<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="TCG">
         <td>Data 1</td>
         <td>Data 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Data 3</td>
         <td>Data 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="TCG">
         <td>Data 5</td>
         <td>Data 6</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Id** is used for individual element identification, please use **class** for select more then one element.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#XL_TCG').change(function () {
        if (!this.checked) 
            $('.abc').fadeIn('slow');
        else 
            $('.abc').fadeOut('slow');
    });
    $('#XL_TCG').change();
});

<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr id="TCG" class="abc">
         <td>Data 1</td>
         <td>Data 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Data 3</td>
         <td>Data 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="TCG" class="abc">
         <td>Data 5</td>
         <td>Data 6</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

IDs can be only addressed once, you need to change your code and use the TCG as class instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#XL_TCG').change(function () {
    if (!this.checked) 
        $('.TCG').fadeIn('slow'); // change to class selector
    else 
        $('.TCG').fadeOut('slow');
});
 $('#XL_TCG').change();
});
```

change HTML

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr class="TCG"> <!-- Change to class -->
     <td>Data 1</td>
     <td>Data 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Data 3</td>
     <td>Data 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="TCG"> <!-- Change to class -->
     <td>Data 5</td>
     <td>Data 6</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the same `id` at multiple places makes your HTML invalid and your site will be punished in SEO for that.

Using your current HTML code, you will be able to make it work like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[id=XL_TCG]').change(function () {
        if (!this.checked) 
            $('[id=XL_TCG]').fadeIn('slow');
        else 
            $('[id=XL_TCG]').fadeOut('slow');
    });
    $('#XL_TCG').change();
});
```

The difference is that in the selector you have been using `#XL_TCG`. This kind of selector is aware that you are referring to an id and will search for it until the first match is found, then it stops. Using the attribute value selector of `[id=XL_TCG]` is not aware that you are searching for an `id` and will not assume that there is a single match. Try this out to have a taste of success. But you are not finished with your task. Make the thing previously known as `id` a `class`, since that is how you intend to use it and update the code accordingly:

#### HTML

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="TCG">
         <td>Data 1</td>
         <td>Data 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Data 3</td>
         <td>Data 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="TCG">
         <td>Data 5</td>
         <td>Data 6</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

#### JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#XL_TCG').change(function () {
        if (!this.checked) 
            $('#TCG').fadeIn('slow');
        else 
            $('#TCG').fadeOut('slow');
    });
    $('#XL_TCG').change();
});
```